# Node import/require files while ignoring file extension?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a shared config file that's used in a lot of places. My code doesn't care what extension the config file has. However, some packages expect it to be `.js`, others expect it to be `.ts`. E.g. if I name it `config.js`, then I can import it with zx and not Capacitor. Vice-versa if I name it `config.ts`.

zx error importing `config.ts`:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for config.ts
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:160:9)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:203:36)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:143:22)
    at async ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:409:7)
    at async ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:291:45) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
```

Capacitor error importing `config.js`:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module config.js from
        capacitor.config.ts not supported.
        Instead change the require of config.js in capacitor.config.ts to a dynamic import() which is
        available in all CommonJS modules.
        at Object.<anonymous> (capacitor.config.ts:3:21)
        at require.extensions..ts (node_modules/@capacitor/cli/dist/util/node.js:35:72)
```

Also sometimes I'd get:

```
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and
        'package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use
        the '.cjs' file extension.
```

The only solution I can think of is just having 2 identical files with different extensions. Is it possible to import/require a file and ignore the extension? E.g. import a `.ts` file and pretend it's a `.js` file, the file won't have any Typescript-specific syntax.